# Construction of open set dense in $R$ with arbitrary small measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can you help me in this, for the moment I have no idea:

> **Exercise 1.2:** For all $\varepsilon >0$ construct an open set $\mathcal{U}$ everywhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and such that $\operatorname*{meas}(\mathcal{U})<\varepsilon$.

Comment: The title of the post is inappropriate. There is no open set in $\mathbb{R}$ with null measure.

Comment: Where's that exercise from? I agree with Amitai: any open non-empty set in the reals contain an open non-trivial interval and thus its measure is non-zero...

Comment: Thanks for the observation guys.

Comment: All he wants is balls of $\epsilon/2^n$ around each rational.It is a dense set with measure less than $\epsilon$.And open as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way. Number the rational numbers however you like. Then using the formula $\sum x^k = 1/(1-x)$, find a number $x$ so that $1/(1-x) < \epsilon$. Now cover the $k$th rational number in your order by an open set of length $x^k$. The sum is bounded above by $\epsilon$, since there will be substantial overlap. This is dense because it contains the rationals as a subset, and they are dense. It is open as a countable union of open sets. So it meets all your criterion.